# Use RegEx or Macro etc. to process / generate text..Macro...Script etc

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to improve / automate some repetitive programming task.

I have a bunch of files (hundreds) like this with some field declarations like this:
(this one has 66 declarations alone)

```
string _id = string.Empty;
string _itemid = string.Empty;
string _upc = string.Empty;
int? _unitid;
...etc...
```

I then have to generate code for each line like this: (first line only of course)

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows modification from default value
/// </summary>
/// <param name="id">blah blah</param>
/// <returns>Builder object to allow fluent method chaining</returns>
public ItemBuilder WithId( string id )
{
   this._id = id;
   return this;
}
```

Everything is boiler plate and there is only two values to be parsed into variables by the regex macro.

The type declaration such as string, int? bool, DateTime etc. This one can be plopped into the boilerplate code as is.

Next the var name would be read such as _id, _itemid, _upc etc. The difference though is some manipulations that need to be done.

1. _id becomes Id and prefixed With to produce WithId.
2. _id becomes id and is plopped into two spots.
3. _id is plopped as is into one spot.

Each line would follow this pattern.

In C# writing a snippet would look like this but the problem comes in getting each line to generate.

```
/// <summary>
/// Allows modification from default value
/// </summary>
/// <param name="$ParmVarName$">Used to assign...to be built with.</param>
/// <returns>Builder object to allow fluent method chaining</returns>
public $BuilderObject$ With$MethodName$( $ParmType$ $ParmVarName$ )
{
  this._$ParmVarName$ = $ParmVarName$;
  return this;
}
```

I was thinking to just copy the declarations (66 in the example above) to a text editor and then run my "macro" against it generating 66 methods that I can then cut and paste back into code file.

So if there was some way in Visual Studio, Edit Plus Plus, LinqPad, etc. to create a template, process the field declarations, and then stuff the template with values from each line I would be very interested in learning....

Please understand I'm not asking you to do my homework [but I won't stop you :)   ] just educate me on what topic / capability I need to learn about.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
^([^\s]+)\s+_([^\s;]+)?.*
```

And extract/replace with:

```
public ItemBuilder With$2( $1 $2 )\n{\n\tthis._$2 = $2;\n\treturn this;\n}
```

See [DEMO](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5E(%5B%5E%5Cs%5D%2B)%5Cs%2B_(%5B%5E%5Cs%3B%5D%2B)%3F.*&i=string%20_id%20%3D%20string.Empty%3B%0D%0Astring%20_itemid%20%3D%20string.Empty%3B%0D%0Astring%20_upc%20%3D%20string.Empty%3B%0D%0Aint%3F%20_unitid%3B&r=public%20ItemBuilder%20With%242(%20%241%20%242%20)%5Cn%7B%5Cn%5Ctthis._%242%20%3D%20%242%3B%5Cn%5Ctreturn%20this%3B%5Cn%7D&o=m)

Comment: This is awesome! I'm am most grateful for your help. It will save me lot of time and knowing about regexstorm.net will be a nice addition to my development resources. One question is that the output has the \n for a new line. Cut and paste is not "translating the \n automatically. This is easy enough to find and replace but figured there was probably some trick I just need to be educated on?

Comment: @user1278561 Yeah.. I tested the regex [here](https://regex101.com/r/aD2rI1/4) and assumed it gets translated in c# too..